# Remove star after \author and remove footnote thereof with achemso

Tags: achemso

I am preparing a report using the `achemso` document class.

I do not want to write an article, hence I do not need to have the * and the footnote "*whom correspondence should be addressed*".

I tried `\author[\empty]{name}` but this messed up the text, and did not solve the problem `\author[]{name}` does not solve the problem either.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Dan

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `achemso` class is _purely for submissions to the ACS_: do not use it if that is not your intention.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol is generated by the macro `\acs@author@fnsymbol`, which you can redefine to be empty.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\makeatletter
\def\acs@author@fnsymbol#1{}
\makeatother

\title{Title of work}
\author{B. Me}
\affiliation{Here Uni.}
\email{bme@here.edu}

\begin{document}



\end{document}
```