# Remove thanks star from author and affiliation

Tags: symbols, affiliation, author

I try to add author and affiliation as follows, but I get a star next to both the name and the affiliation. I have seen some posts about the star symbol ([example1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254964/remove-star-after-author-and-remove-footnote-thereof-with-achemso),[example2](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16568))but I want to use `\thanks` and I have not managed to do this. 
Any ideas how to remove the symbol from both the name and the affiliation?

```
\documentclass[12pr,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-3.0cm}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\title here\\\vspace{1.0cm}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\{\Large something else}}
    \author{name here\thanks{Department here}}

    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the next code into the preamble (before \begin{document}):

```
\makeatletter
\def\thanks#1{\protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you tomacs, that was exactly what I was looking for. Can I ask you if you have a useful source about the \thanks command?

Comment: The original definition of `\thanks` is in the `latex.ltx` file.